# How to lock thread in javascript energy efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to patch the `alert` object in the browser, to show additional text, but I need to await some data to show the necessary content in the alert. However, I can't postpone the `alert` call.

Also, I don't know about a way to close the alert and show another alert without a user action (if it exists, it can solve my problem too).

So, I have to await some data, but I can't break the `alert` behavior, which is blocking execution of the code.

To await a response, I can do something like this:

```js
var start = performance.now();
while(true) {
  var time = performance.now() - start;
  if (time >= 3000) break;
}

console.log('done');
```

But instead of checking the timer, I will check some data.

This way should work, but this is terrible for performance, because it is the opposite to `alert` which is just freezing the thread and does nothing until the close dialog, and we'll load the CPU with useless work.

Is it possible freeze a thread to be more energy efficient?

I have to freeze the thread until I get some data from a worker.

#### Why is promise not solving your problem?

Promises is not blocking a main thread, so this is not reproducing the behavior of `alert` which I need.

#### The blocking thread is not user friendly and it's not that you need to await some data

I know about it, and this note is fair enough to development web pages and applications.

But this case is special. I develop a feature for a
browser extension, to translate alerts. The browser extension must not modify the behavior of the page. So when a web site is calling alert, the thread must be freeze. The browser extension must not postpone an `alert` call to avoid unexpected behavior on the page.

You can see the feature explained here: *[Feat: Implement optional translation of alerts and console logs #102](https://github.com/translate-tools/linguist/issues/102)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to learn about promises and await/async or the classic callback. What you want to do is not going to work.

Comment: You need to RETHINK your idea..... Whatever you are trying to do needs to be structured.

Comment: BTW, `alert`, `prompt` etc are slowly being deprecated.

Comment: This seems to me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Could you elaborate on what are you actually building and why the necessity to block(?) the main thread?

Comment: I see the OP choose to ignore the real problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to "block" without consuming CPU this would be to make a synchronous XMLHttpRequest (which are deprecated because blocking is not user-friendly). You'll need to set up a server that can read the payload of the request and reply after the specified amount of time.

```
const xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
xh.open('GET', urlToYourServer, false);
xh.send('3');
```

where that '3' is the request body that the server parses (and responds after 3 seconds).

That said, **you should not do this** - it's a very inelegant and user-unfriendly approach. It'll stop any other action (including browser repainting and other requests) from occurring while this is going on. Better to properly wait for whatever you need (whether that's through a `.then` of a Promise, or a callback, or something else) - but without more context in the question, how exactly to accomplish this is unclear.

Comment: It's looks like that i need. I'll investigate it and will respond.

I have to lock thread only for current tab, like as `alert` call. Is synchronous XHR will affect on other tabs or browsers engines can optimize it and just freeze thread only for current tab?

Comment: While it's *possible* to block without consuming CPU, I can't see anything good coming of it. Like I said, I'd highly recommend taking a step back and figuring out a better approach. Yes, this will freeze only the current tab.